# Copying CMD output to clipboard

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

I'm trying to copy output from a program running out of the CMD prompt to the Windows clipboard.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            /*Relevant Code*/
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/k cd {0} && backdoor -rt -on -s{1} -p{2}", backdoorDir, pSN, sPPC);
            p.Start();

            p.WaitForExit();
            string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(result);
            }
```

If I were to enter this directly into CMD, it would look like this:

First Command (change directory):

```
cd C:\users\chris\appdata\roaming\backdoor
```

Second Command (Launches backdoor, a cmd tool. Arguments follow.):

```
backdoor -rt -on -sCCDXE -p14453
```

And when doing this through CMD, I get this result:

```
The backdoor password is: 34765

C:\users\chris\appdata\roaming\backdoor>
```

However, when running my C# code, this is the only thing that gets added to my clipboard:

```
C:\users\chris\appdata\roaming\backdoor>
```

Why isn't it capturing "The backdoor password is: 34765?" It's like the `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` isn't reading everything.

Comment: Try using `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true` and `p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `ReadToEnd` before `WaitForExit`

Chris' code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*Relevant Code*/
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/k cd {0} && backdoor -rt -on -s{1} -p{2}", backdoorDir, pSN, sPPC);
        p.Start();

        string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(result);
    }
```

Sample console app code:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dir";
        p.Start();

        string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

- argument `/C` executes the command and then terminates the cmd process. This is necessary for this code to work. Otherwise, it will wait for ever.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I made the change you suggested by putting "wait" after "read." When I click the button to execute in my program, I get a CMD window that appears with the following: `The backdoor password is: 34765`. But it's writing `C:\users\chris\appdata\roaming\backdoor>` to my clipboard still, as well as Console.WriteLine(), which I've added to rule out any potential clipboard issues.

Comment: This all is correct. I just needed to use the RedirectStandardError instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One reson **may** well be that the program is **not** actually writing to `StdOut` but to the screen directly.

Test this by piping the output into a file:

```
backdoor -rt -on -sCCDXE -p14453 > c:\text.txt
```

If the new file doesn't contain the output either then you are stuck and may need to look into screen scraping..